# Python TCP connection not establishing in a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I am writing a Python program for a chat session between multiple clients. In order to have multiple clients connect, `_thread` module is used to create the TCP connection. However, whenever I try to establish the TCP connection in the thread I would get `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused` right on line `tcp_socket.connect((IP, TCP_PORT))`.

The same line of code works perfectly fine when done without threading so it is not a problem concerning TCP port number. Also, the same exact code works perfectly fine on Windows machine. This is happening in Mac and Linux only for some reason. What is the problem here??

server.py:

```
from _thread import *
import socket

def createClientConnection(client_id, client_address):
    tcp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    tcp_socket.bind((IP, TCP_PORT))
    tcp_socket.listen()
    client_socket, address = tcp_socket.accept() # This doesn't print, and thread just ends
    print("\n* TCP socket bound to %s\n" %(TCP_PORT))
    ...

IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 1234
...

start_new_thread(createClientConnection, (client_id, client_address))
# when I do the tcp socket connection here instead of the start_new_thread,
# TCP connection is created normally.
```

client.py:

```
import socket

IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 1234
...

tcp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcp_socket.connect((IP, TCP_PORT))  # Error 61 right here
print("\n* TCP socket created\n")
```

Not using multithreading is not a preferrable option for me due to other project specs. Above are much simplified version of the original code, but this is the essence of the error I am getting.

Comment: Why `_thread` module instead of `threading`?

Comment: Put a try/except with print in createClientConnection to catch more error paths. Also, is ConnectionRefusedError in the server.py thread or client.py? Its not the sort of error i'd expect on an accept call.

Comment: @tdelaney The question says it's happening on the `connect()` call, not `accept()`, so it's the client.

Comment: Typically the way you structure a server like this is with a main thread that calls `accept()` in a loop. When a new client connects, it spawns a worker thread to manage that connection.

Comment: Where do `client_id` and `client_address` come from if you spawn the thread before accepting the connection?

Comment: "Connection refused" means the server isn't running yet. Are you sure you're spawning the server thread before you start the client?

Comment: My guess is that you need tcp_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) on the server before the bind so that the port isn't in timed-wait on the next time you try to use it. And certainly don't have multiple threads do socket/bind on the server. Usually you create threads after the accept.

Comment: @barmar OP also says _whenever I try to establish the TCP connection in the thread_ so its not clear what is going on. I'm just trying to clear up the ambiguities.

Comment: @tdelaney I think he means "Whenever I put the server code in a thread (rather than main-line code), I get that error when I try to escablish the connection (in the client)"

Comment: @tdelaney You may be right, but if you don't use `SO_REUSEADDR` when needed, the `socket.bind()` call should raise an exception.

Comment: @Barmar - I think that's what is happening but OP doesn't catch exceptions in the server thread so doesn't see it.

Comment: @tdelaney Shouldn't it just crash the server and print the error message? Or does threading hide that?

Comment: @barmar - an exception in a thread doesn't stop the main thread. (well, something like a pool.map would propagate back but that's because of map's implementation). By default, you'd expect a log message on stderr. So, you 'd see something if you ran it on the command line. But in some sort of an IDE, maybe not.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I tried using ```threading``` as well, but it would give me the same error at the same spot.

Comment: @Barmar I simplified code for easy viewing but ```client_id``` and ```client_address``` are hardcoded in ```server.py```. When spawning connection, I always make sure to run ```server.py``` before ```client.py``` so the server thread is always spawned first.

Also, your interpretation for the line *whenever I try to establish the TCP connection* is correct.

Comment: As I said, servers don't connect to the client. The client connects to the server, the server accepts the connection, and then uses that connection.

Comment: @tdelaney I did try using ```tcp_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR``` as well, but no luck.

Comment: @Barmar I think in that process the server is not accepting the connection for some reason. I could try to add some more try/excepts and see if that tells me anything, but so far I've checked that everything runs just fine up to the ```listen()``` in the server side, then I get the error from the client side.

Comment: As I also said, you should accept the connection in the main thread, and spawn the worker *after* that happens.

Comment: @Barmar AHH!!! so I had up to ```tcp_socket.accept()``` in the main code and *then* started the thread and it works now! I see, I don't know why didn't understand this before... Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you’re running it with sudo. If you’re on MacOs, they have some issues when you make raw sockets, so just run it as:

```
sudo python <filename>
```

Then enter your password for your computer.

Hope I helped here :)

Comment: You only have to run as root to bind ports under 1024. Port 1234 should be OK.